# “Next comments” or “following comments”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Which would be more correct: “next comments” or “following comments” in the sentence: “Save my name and email for my next comments”? This sentence is used in the context of saving user's data for automatic input of them in user's future comments on a website.

I am asking whether reader wants (or not) to save his name and email address for his future comments. This is the label of the checkbox. This question is about the usage of the word, not the article usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither works well. It sounds as if the name and email will be included in those future comments.

If someone has just provided their name and email in order to write a comment, then the purpose of the name and email should be clear, so a simple checkbox labeled "Save my name and email address" should be sufficient, perhaps with a link "why" that opens a popup explaining the purpose.

Comment: Author's name is published on site, and email isn't. Does this detail change your answer?

Comment: This is really a UX question, I'm not an expert. However I don't think "for next comments" or "for following comments" works well. So it doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites use the label:

> Keep me logged in

With that label, it is irrelevant what you save.

(Of course, I assume that there is some login / logout feature implemented)

Comment: On that site there is simply comment form with no login / logout feature. Comments are public, but in order to send one, there is need to enter email into form.